# Row inside FrameLabel doesn't work in Mathematica 9

Tags: plotting, version-9, labeling

So as to automate/customize plot titles I use `Row` inside e.g. FrameLabel:
`FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", Row[...]}`

Now with Mathematica 9, the plot doesn't show the bit referring to Row. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem exists when using `Graphics` directly?  I would like to add to or change the tags to include `Graphics` as I expect this is a more general and lower level problem than `Plot`.  For example: `Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", Row[{"a", "b", "c"}, "+"]}]`

Comment: I checked and it works fine with `Graphics`. This issue seems to affect only `Plot` and related (e.g. `ListContourPlot`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me on V9

```
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {{"x", "y"}, {Row[{"this ", 1, "is ", 3, " test"}], 
                     Row[{"this is a title in row"}]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ofcourse it will help everyone if you posted an actual code example that shows the problem you are having.

Comment: In Mathematica 8 this was working:  
`Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", Row[{"a", "b", "c"}, "+"]}]`

After seeing your example I realized that now I have to rewrite the previous code as:  
`Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {"x", Row[{"a", "b", "c"}, "+"]}}]`

Comment: funny though that `Graphics` still accepts the sloppy way `FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", Row[{"a", "b", "c"}, "+"]}`